# C - how to print the value of the pointer [0][0] in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, enums

I want to print a board like this: [image]

And in the given code, I have these values (unchangeable code):

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#define BOARD_WIDTH 10
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 10

typedef enum cell
{
    EMPTY, //0
    BLOCKED, //1
    PLAYER //2
} Cell;

#define EMPTY_OUTPUT " "

Cell BOARD_1[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
Cell BOARD_2[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);
void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);
```

I have tried writing the initialiseBoard() in many ways like:

```
void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
    int i, j;
    int *temp = NULL;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            board[i][j] = EMPTY;
}

void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
    int i, j;
    int *temp = NULL;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                *temp = EMPTY;
                board[0][0] = temp;
            }
            else
                board[i][j] = EMPTY;
        }
}
```

Because I know the first cell in the board at [0][0] is a pointer, so I tried many ways to get its referenced value but it always return an address. Please have a look at the code below and suggest me an approach. Thank you very much!

```
void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("\t|%s|", EMPTY_OUTPUT);
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                printf("%d|", j);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    printf("\t|%d|", i - 1);
                else
                {
                    char* c;

                    /*unsigned *p = &board[0][0];

                    if (i == 1 && j == 1)
                        c = (*p == EMPTY) ? EMPTY_OUTPUT : "?";*/

                    if (i == 1 && j == 1)
                        c = (board[0][0] == EMPTY) ? EMPTY_OUTPUT : "?";
                    else
                        c = (board[i - 1][j - 1] == EMPTY) ? EMPTY_OUTPUT : "?";
                    printf("%s|", c);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", board[0][0]); 
}
```

When I run displayBoard(): [image]

At [0][0], it always returns an address.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A pointer _is_ an address. Do you wish to print the data that this pointer points to? As it stands, you've set the value that tmp points to to hold 0 (EMPTY), you've then set the value of [0][0] to hold the address that tmp (a pointer, _NOT_ the value EMPTY) resides at.

Comment: The first cell is no different from any other, so you don't need to handle it in any specific way. Also you're complicating things by using the 0 in the loop for printing the borders. Just print them outside the loop. You also haven't shown how you call these functions.

Comment: Please turn your compiler's warning/error reporting up to reasonable settings. You'd get a notice of the problem @enhzflep mentioned immediately, since you're converting `int*` to `int`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - good advice, I didn't think of that - I imagine my comment was somewhat unhelpful to Jay in retrospect.

Comment: when I just print the value of board[0][0] as normal, it also returns an address. I tried that way already. I was so confused of what address that board[0][0] is pointing to and whether that address is pointing to another address... however, enhzflep just helped me understand another thing as in your comment.

Comment: Your second `initialiseBoard` function does wrong and unnecessary things. Why aren't you satisfied with the first version?

Comment: so you mean the one I use unsigned *p? It also printed an address as well :(

Comment: this premise: *Because I know the first cell in the board at [0][0] is a pointer* is not correct, it is a instance of a `Cell`.  From there forward, the code fails.   Note: the displayed board is 11x11 with special conditions for all of row 0 and special conditions for every column 0

Comment: Note: this `" "` is two characters a space and a '\0'  Naturally, that does not fit into a `Cell`

Answer (score 0):

`board[0][0]` is just a base address of your 2d array 
and it is printing the base address of your 2d array if you want to print value at address then you should use `'*'` it shows the value at address in your case you should use `*((board+0)+0)`
you can try this and let me know if there is any issue :)

Comment: The last statement - can you remove that! If you're not 'damm sure' then why did you write up the answer? Revise your answer.

Comment: It is the same as `board[0][0]`

Comment: I tried it and got this warning when compiling: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'Cell *'

Comment: sorry for that actually write not i dont have environment to compile c code thats why i said that, but thanks to guide me I am a new user of it, I am removing it

Answer (score 0):

The first initialiseBoard() function is the one that you want to use. That properly sets all the 2d array elements to EMPTY.

When displaying the board remember that the address of the array itself and the address of [0][0] are the same address. To see the value stored at [0][0] you dereference the array. The value stored in the array element is the number corresponding to the enum that you defined.

```
   unsigned *arrayAddress = &board[0][0];
   printf( "2d array address is %p\n", arrayAddress );

   int arrayElemContent = board[0][0];
   printf( "2d array [0][0] content is %d\n", arrayElemContent );

   board[0][0] = BLOCKED;
   printf( "blocked is %d\n", board[0][0] );
```

In this case the element that you retrieve from the array is an int from the enum that you defined earlier, so you print it using %d.